# AStar taking care of collisions for a rectangle

Tags: path-finding

How can I explore a path with A* (or another) by taking care of a rectangle collision ?

I have a 2d map, where I know for each coordinate if it is an obstacle :

[image: map view with Tiled Map Editor software]

For example, dark tiles are not traversable :

[image: map view with my game engine]

I use [A* algorithm to find path](https://github.com/buxx/OpenCombat/blob/master/src/physics/path.rs#L4), where for a given point, all around successor are possible [with a variable cost](https://github.com/buxx/OpenCombat/blob/master/src/map/mod.rs#L194). There is a visual example (game is top view):

[image: path finding example]

How can I make a A* (or other) algorithm taking care of obstacles for a (for example) vehicle ?. In the previous image example, a man can use this path, but tank. should not

Comment: You may be interested in [Path finding in grid for objects that occupy more than one tile](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14009/39518), [Multi-tile agent path-finding algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18050/39518), [Pathfinding with different sized units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/53492/39518), and [Pathfinding for units of variable size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/28222/39518).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a different graph for a different kind of unit.

For example a graph for humans, a graph for land vehicles, a graph for water vehicles, and so on.

And there is no change to the algorithm. The difference is that each graph is created considering the space and the type of terrain that the kind of unit requires.

And yes, that means it would be convenient to have some standard spacing so you don't have to create graph for each individual unit type, but you can reuse them for similar unit types.

*For clarity: A square grid is a kind of graph, and this approach is not limited to square grids.*

Comment: Hello Theraot. Thanks for your time. Do you have any advice about considering the space of vehicle when computing successors of a coordinate?

Comment: @bux If you are talking about maneuverability, you can generate that dynamically, see 
[Pathfinding With Speed Based Turning Restrictions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/178877/10408).

Comment: [Note that you can also re-use one grid for agents of all sizes using a distance field representation as explained here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/175384/39518).